# How to handle Zombies in a non-deterministic orchestration?

Tags: biztalk

I am creating a non-deterministic orchestration to handle convoys.  I know I am setting up for the classic 'zombie' pattern.  What have you done to handle the zombies when this sort of pattern is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point is make sure that it really necessary, can you avoid it? Read this first:

http://www.modhul.com/2008/06/08/yet-another-non-deterministic-biztalk-zombie-pattern/

Only thing I can think of, is that you have a routine for monitoring and cleaning up suspended instances.